# Display calendar in modal form popup

Tags: javascript, html

I have modal form to pick time but the calendar is behind modal form when modal form display. I want calendar display on the modal form

```js
#
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker();
$('#datetimepicker2').datepicker();
$(document).on('click', '#btn_ok', function() {
  alert($('#datetimepicker1').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> #

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Chọn thời gian</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label style="padding-right: 10px">Từ</label>
          <div class="input-group date" data-target-input="nearest">
            <input type="text" id="datetimepicker1" class="form-control datetimepicker-input">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn_ok">OK</button>
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Spangle what do you mean, bro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements can overlap for a variety of reasons. Increase the z-index of **datepicker-div**. z-index only affects elements that have a position. and datepicker have position fixed.

result - https://www.screencast.com/t/dkpeBNbcpJq

```
 //Add in style file.
    div#ui-datepicker-div {
        z-index: 9999 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the z-index of the datepicker more than the modal's z-index